# Season 6 Finale: Has there been any information about this character's fate?

Tags: true-blood

In the season 6 finale of True Blood, (S06E10)

> Eric is shown going up in flame as the fairy blood's effect wears off.

Has there been any information about this character's fate? I'd see any interviews with cast/crew to see if the actor will be returning for Season 7 (although in this universe, the actor returning doesn't necessarily mean the character will be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The show runner now confirms he is alive ! but a bit crispy and the consequences of firebathing

http://www.digitalspy.co.uk/ustv/s59/true-blood/news/a508565/alexander-skarsgard-will-return-to-true-blood-showrunner-confirms.html

Comment: Your link doesn't confirm he's alive, just that the actor will be a series regular.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, [we know](http://insidetv.ew.com/2013/08/20/true-blood-season-6-finale/) that Eric will return, but the showrunners are keeping quiet on the subject of Eric surviving:

> ENTERTAINMENT WEEKLY: You’ve confirmed that Alexander Skarsgard will return and be a regular on the show next season. Eric’s alive!
>
> BRIAN BUCKNER: [Laughs] Well, I did not confirm that he’s alive. Not that I want to create more conversation, because I don’t, but to be clear, we’re not saying how we’re going to use him, we’re simply saying that we are using him. I will say that I do long for the days when television audiences could stand to wait and enjoy the tease. But I understand we’re living in a different time. I don’t want to watch a show without him either.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Guess I'll have to patiently wait for the next season.

Answer (score 2):

A belated return to this question, which I was surprised to find did not get an updated answer during season seven.

[Eric Northman tells Sookie what happened](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68205/how-did-a-certain-character-survive-post-season-6-finale-spoilers) in the fourth episode of season seven (S07E04, "Death Is Not the End"):

> “First I went home to Sweden, which was beautiful. But unfortunately,
>  I triggered an avalanche that killed an entire ski village. Things got
>  a little hectic after that.”

From there it is simple to deduce that

> he saved himself by diving in to the snow, which caused said avalanche.