# How did a certain character survive post-Season 6 finale? [spoilers]

Tags: true-blood

If you haven't watched up to S07 E02 yet, here be spoilers...

In the Season 6 finale,

> Eric is shown bursting into flames after Jason kills Warlow, thereby negating Eric's ability to safely "daywalk" after ingesting Warlow's fairy blood.

We assume the worst, but then they are seen to have survived in season 7.

I am wondering how this character managed to achieve this, especially given that

> from what I can recall of past episodes, combustion seems to be almost instantaneous and irretrievably fatal, **when a vamp is exposed to full broad daylight** (as opposed to the slow and gradual hissing/smoking effect observed when some natural light feeds into a room through a window, etc.).

As far as I can recall, no explanation for this was provided within the show and we are left to speculate how the heck they pulled it off.

Maybe my memory of "how it works" based on previous episodes is wrong, or maybe I simply missed whatever point where a reasonable explanation for this character's survival was given. Whatever the case, I'd appreciate some kind of answer if it's out there!

Please note, I am aware of the existence of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39658/season-6-finale-has-there-been-any-information-about-this-characters-fate), but the nature of my question is different: I'm not asking what happened to them, I'm trying to discern the means by which they actually got to that point.

For what it's worth, here's my best hypothesis for the moment:

> It takes at least a few seconds before the vamp is fatally burned, and within those few seconds Eric was able to muster the strength and presence of mind to burrow into the snow and out of direct sunlight (though he must have had to dig in deep enough and fast enough that he was still sheltered even after immediately surrounding snow had melted from the heat of his body). Or, he could have dived under his sun-lounge, if the fabric was opaque enough to block out the light and didn't also catch alight. Another possible element of this is that even if there would NOT normally be a few seconds before the flames are fatal, maybe Warlow's blood was powerful enough that the fact he'd had it in his system for a few weeks/months etc. was sufficient to somewhat preserve his body for just that little bit longer before he would have been fatally affected.

Looking forward to hearing other people's theories - thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

[Eric sort of explained it in episode S07E04, "Death Is Not the End"](http://www.hitfix.com/monkeys-as-critics/recap-true-blood-death-is-not-the-end):

> “First I went home to Sweden, which was beautiful. But unfortunately,
>  I triggered an avalanche that killed an entire ski village. Things got
>  a little hectic after that.”

From there it is simple to deduce that he saved himself

> by diving in to the snow, which caused said avalanche.

Comment: That makes a reasonable amount of sense, although I find it odd that if that is indeed what he's referring to, he doesn't phrase it as "Things got a little hectic, **and then** I triggered..." etc. One would think that the precursor event would be the more hectic part of that sequence?...

Comment: I don't think bursting into flames and jumping in the snow constitutes "full of incessant or frantic activity"; whereas dealing with the fall-out of the avalanche would be more in line with that. But I think he mainly uses it as sort of an excuse, kinda like "I've been busy."